# Pareto graph in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text, pareto-chart

I managed to create a Pareto chart, however, I would like to improve certain things but I lack the skills to do it. Maybe someone could have a quick look at the graph and let me know, if

1. I can have on the right y-axis, where *Cumulative frequencies(%)* are, I could have the percentage symbol after the numbers? This way I could remove the axis title, which would be great
2. In case number 1 is not possible, how can I make the right y-axis title bigger? The `size = 12` cannot be entered and I am not sure how that would work out. I was also considering to rotate the title but again I am not sure if this is doable
3. Is it possible to rotate the *A,B,C,D...* labels so that they are not vertical but horizontal?
4. I was wondering if adding relative frequencies above the bars is an option, as well as percentages above the dots on the red curve, which represent the cumulative frequencies?

#### Minimal example

```
set.seed(42)  ## for sake of reproducibility
c <- data.frame(value=factor(paste("value", 1:n)),counts=sample(18:130, n, replace=TRUE))
```

#### Cumulative frequnecies for pareto chart

```
# It's maybe not the most elegant way of doing it but it works
# If someone can offer an alternative, that would be nice

df <- data.frame(c,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df <- df[order(df$counts,decreasing=TRUE), ]

df$value <- factor(df$value, levels=df$value)

df$cumulative <- cumsum(df$counts)

df$cumulative <- 100 * df$cumulative/tail(df$cumulative, n=1)

scaleRight <- tail(df$cumulative, n=1)/head(df$counts, n=1)
```

#### Pareto chart in ggplot

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=value)) +  theme_bw()+
  geom_bar(aes(y=counts, fill=value), stat="identity",show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_path(aes(y=cumulative/scaleRight, group=1),colour="red", size=0.9) +
  geom_point(aes(y=cumulative/scaleRight, group=1),colour="red") +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*scaleRight, name = "Cumulative (%)"), n.breaks = 9) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.6)) +
  theme(
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        panel.background =element_blank(),panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=12),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=12)) +
  scale_color_grey(start=0, end=.6)+scale_fill_grey()+ ylab("Counts")
```

#### Output

[image: Pareto Chart]

Comment: 1) `sec_axis(..., labels = scales::percent)`. 3) comment out the 1st `theme`. 2) Have you tried `axis.text.y.right = element_text(size=12)`?

Comment: `axis.text.y.right = element_text(size=12` this will make the title bigger only on the left y-axis but not on the right y-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I love your question, you have put a great deal of effort into asking a good question with a reproducible example and working code (except `n` wasn't defined, but usually I can count to 7).

First off, I have taken the liberty to refactor your data manipulation code using tidyverse's `dplyr`. It makes it much more succinct to read. I furthermore avoided multiplying your cummulative percentage with 100, and you will see why. Also, I didn't get the same values as you did.

```
set.seed(42)  ## for sake of reproducibility
n <- 6
c <- data.frame(value=factor(paste("value", 1:n)),counts=sample(18:130, n, replace=TRUE))
dput(c)
structure(list(value = structure(1:6, .Label = c("value 1", "value 2", 
"value 3", "value 4", "value 5", "value 6"), class = "factor"), 
    counts = c(66L, 118L, 82L, 42L, 91L, 117L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

df <- c %>%
  arrange(desc(counts)) %>%
  mutate(
    value = factor(value, levels=value),
    cumulative = cumsum(counts) / sum(counts)
  ) 

df
    value counts cumulative
1 value 2    118  0.2286822
2 value 6    117  0.4554264
3 value 5     91  0.6317829
4 value 3     82  0.7906977
5 value 1     66  0.9186047
6 value 4     42  1.0000000
```

The *A, B, C, D* labels you are referring to, I assume are the x-axis labels. These have been rotated a quarter with the command (in your code!) - it's the `angle=90` that caused it.

```
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.6))
```

All in all, I propose the following solution:

```
f <- max(df$counts) # or df$counts[1], as it is sorted descendingly

ggplot(df, aes(x=value)) +  theme_bw(base_size = 12)+
  geom_bar(aes(y=counts, fill=value), stat="identity",show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_path(aes(y=cumulative*f, group=1),colour="red", size=0.9) +
  geom_point(aes(y=cumulative*f, group=1),colour="red") +
  scale_y_continuous("Counts", sec.axis = sec_axis(~./f, labels = scales::percent), n.breaks = 9) +
  scale_fill_grey() +
  theme(
    axis.text = element_text(size=12),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x=element_blank()
  )
```

[image]

In response to questions:

Adding labels can be done with `geom_text`:

```
geom_text(aes(label=sprintf('%.0f%%', cumulative*100), y=cumulative*f), colour='red', nudge_y = 5) +
geom_text(aes(label=sprintf('%.0f%%', counts/sum(counts)*100), y=counts), nudge_y = 5) +
```

Note the use of `nudge_y` - this one may be difficult, because it works in the major y-axis scale, so nudging by "5" units here makes sense, but if your counts were in the thousands, "5" is not enough.

**Please note** that the solutions given here, only works as long as `c` (and `df`) contains the entire scope of values; i.e. if you 8 or 10 or more faults, but only want to show the 6 main faults, the calculations of cummulative sums and percentages will be wrong.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to address my question and offering a more elegant solution with all explanations. It will help me to understand your course of thoughts. The graph looks exactly how I wanted to have it (I will still remove the left y-axis title "Counts" but that is easy). Thank you for pointing out that actually I (ugh....) put the rotation of the labels; I've simply overseen it. Would it be still possible to put the cumulative frequencies above the red dots and relative frequencies above the bars?

Comment: I will double-check the values on my end to see what eventually went wrong there.

Comment: I know what went wrong, I attached a graph when n wasn't 7 but of a different value, so all is good here